Internet sharing for ower PC connected via Ethernet
I have two computers connected to each other by an Ethernet connection. One is Linux, the other is Windows. The Internet is connected via a USB modem connected to a Windows machine.
Both computers have static IP addresses. In Windows:
192.168.20.2
255.255.255.0

In Linux:
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth1 inet static 
address 192.168.20.6 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.20.254 
dns-nameservers 192.168.20.254 8.8.8.8
auto eth1

And I need the addresses to remain static.
I can't get internet on my Linux machine.
I tried using a network bridge, but it did not help - if I connect a network adapter to the bridge, the Internet still does not appear on the Linux machine. If I add a USB modem to the bridge, the Internet disappears on the Windows machine.

Windows has a share internet option - are you using that? I ran its predecessor ~20 years ago, and I think it handles the firewall settings it needs. Getting that working would be a first step.

Why are you pointing your Linux box at a gateway that doesn't exist? If there's nothing on this Ethernet LAN but these two machines, then who is .254? If the Windows machine at .2 is the device with the USB modem that connects to the Internet, the Linux machine should be using .2 as its gateway, not a nonexistent .254. Also, the Windows box needs to be running a NAT gateway. Is it?

@Подмастерье Компьютерщик
In this case need use dinamic IP addres.

@Spiff Yes this is not correct gateway. I'm really bad at this.
Could you tell  more about  NAT gateway?

NAT is what allows one device with a single routable IP address to allow additional devices to get Internet access through it. You can't just transparently bridge traffic from Ethernet to the USB modem interface because the Linux box's 192.168 address is a nonroutable private IP address so your ISP will ignore packets with that source address. Your ISP will only accept packets from the IP address they give your USB modem interface when it connects, so you must use NAT to make the Linux box's traffic seem like it's coming from that address.

It doesn't make a difference which one you plug the modem into, but you need to plug the ethernet cord of one computer directly into the ethernet on the other computer.  Then, go to the computer with internet, open the settings of that ethernet adapter and turn on internet connection sharing (on linux, it's "Shared to other computers").

@JayCravens  When I do this, a message appears that if other computers use static addresses, I should configure them to use dynamic addresses

@Spiff  In the dispatcher Hyper-v i create external virtual switcha and connet to USB modem (Remote NDIS). But the Internet never appeared.
And I don't see any settings. Everything I found on the Internet concerns virtual machines, or servers, switches.

If you're using windows for internet, then linux = address 192.168.20.6 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.20.2 dns-nameservers 192.168.20.2 8.8.8.8

@JayCravens In the properties of the network connection of the USB modem (Remote NDIS) -> Access -> Allow anower user use internet connection.  In Home network Connection i select  ethernet network conection.
After that, in ethernet connection,  I change IP at 192.168.20.2
mask 255.255.255.0
DNS 8.8.8.8
Alt DNS 8.8.4.4
I tried the same without DNS, but still there is no Internet on the Linux machine

Not the modem.  You are receiving data via USB port, correct?  Go to that computers eithernet connection, and turn on the internet connection sharing, which will create the NAT bridge for you to the linux PC.  Then just change the settings on the linux computer to the ones above, using the .2 address for gateway/DNS.

@JayCravens In Windows mashine i have two connection Ethernet 2(Remote NDIS) - USB modem,  and Ethernet 1 (Realtek) - ethernet connection with Linux mashine.
In Windows PC, in  Network connections → Ethernet 2(Remote NDIS)-> Propertis-> Access-> set Allow anower user use internet connection.
In Home network Connection folder i select Ethernet 1 (Realtek).
After that, in Ethernet 1 i change ip to static 192.168.2.2. Is this what you meant?  For some reason this doesn't work for me

ICS on the Windows machine, it effectively turns the host into a NAT (Network Address Translation) router. This allows it to bridge and forward network traffic between the connected devices on the internal network (192.127.x.x which is what windows will use for the bridging) and the external network (192.168.20.x).  You shouldn't have to change anything, ICS will forward it.

Check the windows firewall settings if the linux pc still has no internet, it's famous for it.  Make it all "Trusted Zone".  You could switch the linux adapter to dynamic also, as a test.  But ICS will give you a 192.127.x.x address, so then it wouldn't meet your questions full criteria of static addressing.

@JayCravens Terminology note: bridging refers to 802.1D. NAT is not a method of bridging. It's a distinctly different way to forward packets from one interface to another. I think it muddles the discussion if you talk of a "NAT bridge" or say that enabling NAT allows bridging. It's possible to enable both at the same time, but NAT by itself is not bridging.

Yes, I should have said "This causes it...", and saying "NAT bridge" was just an extremely condensed explanation & completely improper, for sure.

@JayCravens The Internet appeared when I changed the default gateway to 192.168.20.2 using
sudo route add default gw 192.168.20.2 eth0
But after rebooting the Linux machine, it again becomes
192.168.20.254
Although in /etc/network/interfaces
The correct gateway 192.168.20.2 is registered
